# False boolean = True?

Tags: java, boolean

I found this code in a book and I executed it in Netbeans:

```
boolean b = false;
if(b = true) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

I just don't understand why the output of this code is true,
Can anyone enlighten me please,
Thanks.

Comment: This code also demonstrates why testing booleans for equality with `true` or `false` is not only pointless but dangerous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's missing the double-equals.  So it's doing an assignment instead of an equality comparison (and remember, the return value of an assignment is the new value). In most cases, the fact that most types are not boolean means the result is not a boolean and so it becomes illegal for an `if` statement, resulting in a compiler error.  However, since the type here is already a boolean, the assignment results in a boolean and so the safety-check fails.  Thus, `b = true` means that `b` is assigned the value `true` and this is the value that is returned and checked by the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the if-statement condition isn't a comparison. It's an assignment:

```
if(b = true)
```

Which will always return true. So it will always print `true`.

If you wanted to do a comparison, you need to use `==`.

Comment: If you aren't getting a warning about this, your compiler/ide warning settings need to be cranked up.

Comment: this answer is wrong? im getting false if(b=false) (as in purposeful assignment) like logically toggling b=true;return b=false

Comment: @Nik Generally speaking, you shouldn't be trying to write cryptic code like that. While it may be convenient for you, it could easily confuse the next person trying to read your code.

Comment: if it's commented and goes with the style, i dont see a problem. verbose code is not always good..... think if you have a lot of specialized calculations for something that needs to be really fast. i was just surprised to see a test case fail

Comment: @Nik Please understand that shorter != faster. Also we're getting off-topic here. What does this have to do with my answer?

Comment: as far as i understood it prints true if assignment is a success.... thus if b=false, it should print true, because a value got assigned?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. The assignment is always a "success". But the assignment operator returns the value that was assigned. The if-statement then takes that value. Since it assigned true and returns true, it enters the if-statement and prints true.

Answer (score 2):

In your "if" statement you are assigning the value "true" to b. You should check the value by using the comparison operator "==".

```
boolean b = false;

if(b == true)
{
   System.out.println("true");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("false");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(b = true)
```

Well it is true because = is the assignment operator and not the equality operator ==

Answer (score 0):

`if (b = true)` assigns the value `true` to `b`, and then acts on that true value.  That's the danger of C-like languages, that if you leave out the second `=` when you meant to compare, you get an assignment instead, and an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is an assignment. You don't do a check on b, you just assign true to it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of int x having 2 possible values, either 1 or 0. If x = 1, then do this. Else, (x = 0) then do something else. Boolean is just saying it is either one condition, or not that condition.