# boolean is assigned but never accessed

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I'm just trying to create a GuessMyNumber game and here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class classic {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean beaten = false;
    int number;
    int randn = rand.nextInt(99);
    //System.out.println(randn);
    System.out.println("What is my number? Guess it!");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
     while(beaten = true){
            number = input.nextInt();
            if (number == randn) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                beaten = true;
            }
            if (number < randn) {
                System.out.println(number + " is too low");
            }
            if (number > randn) {
                System.out.println(number + " is too high");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the while loop I set `beaten = true` but still, while loop continues

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `while(beaten = true){` `=` is assignment operator `==` is comparison. Use `while(beaten == true)` or better to avoid problems like the one you are currently having `while(beaten)` (or `while(!beaten)` if you want `while(beaten == false)`).

Comment: Use `while (!beaten) { ... }`.

Comment: @aioobe @Pshemo Ahh It Worked but what does `!` mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [False boolean = True?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883502/false-boolean-true)

Comment: @belkipAndroidness, `!` means "not". `while (!beaten)` means loop while not beaten (i.e. loop until `beaten` is true)

Answer (score 2):

```
while(beaten = true)
```

As `=` is an assignment operator, so `true` is assigned into `beaten` first, then `while loop` condition becomes,

```
beaten = true
while(true) {
//.... hence, loop executed.
}
```

Use comparison operator `==` for condition checking. Moreover, *not* `!` operation can be used also for `boolean` variable.

Say,

```
beaten = true
```

Then

```
while(!beaten)
```

means

```
while(!true) // read while not true
//implies
while(false) {
//.... loop will not going to execute.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guess {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean beaten = false;
    int number;
    int randn = rand.nextInt(99);
    //System.out.println(randn);
    System.out.println("What is my number? Guess it!");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
     while(beaten == false ){
            number = input.nextInt();
            if (number == randn) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                beaten = true;
            }
            if (number < randn) {
                System.out.println(number + " is too low");
                counter++;
            }
            if (number > randn) {
                System.out.println(number + " is too high");
                counter++;
            }
        }
     System.out.print("It took you " + counter + " tries to gues the number");
    }
}
```

Now it works. You set "beaten" to false originally so it wasn't working and I also changed your while loop condition too "beaten == false" instead of "beaten = false" Hope this helps. I didn't know what you wanted to do with the counter so I just added that into the bottom to count how many tries it took.

Comment: When you set "boolean beaten = false" and then your while loop said "while(beaten = true)" it made the code skip over your while loop

Comment: why "beaten == false" works, the boolean itself is already false why is it looping it?

Comment: You aren't redefining "beaten" as false when you say "beaten == false". All that does is see if "beaten" is false or true. so "beaten == false" says while beaten equals false then execute the loop. "beaten = false" actually means that you are setting "beaten" to equal false. I hope I answered what you are asking

Comment: maybe I can't understand I don't know,I know that "==" isn't assignment, but Doesn't "while" means "while(expression){statement} do the statement until expression is true"        I already set the boolean at the top "boolean beaten = false" its already false why it loops?

Comment: This explains is pretty well: "www.javabeat.net/what-is-difference-between-equals-and/"

Comment: when it says ".equals()" that is the same thing as "="